# Grey out items in disabled ListView

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I am writing an application in `C++` using `WinAPI`.
I have a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of items with checkboxes and a scrollbar. Sometimes I need to disable the whole thing. When I call [EnableWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do that, the behavior of `ListView` is ok. It gets disabled, none of the contents are accessible any more. However checkboxes and scrollbar still look normal (not grayed out as the rest of the element).

Is it possible to grey out all parts within the `ListView`?

Enabled[image]
Disabled[image]

Normal disabled checkbox looks liks this: [image] <- this is how I would expect to see checkboxes in the `ListView`, same applies to the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the checkboxes, the documentation for [`LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732.aspx) says:

> When set to this style, the control creates and sets a state image list with two images using DrawFrameControl. State image 1 is the unchecked box, and state image 2 is the checked box. Setting the state image to zero removes the check box.

You can therefore just change those images at indices 1 and 2 in the image list to their properly disabled variants when you are disabling the whole control.

The process itself of course varies depending on the framework you are using (if any), but generally will be along the lines of creating an Image List of SM_CXSMICON×SM_CYSMICON icons, creating a bitmap (2*SM_CXSMICON × SM_CYSMICON) pixels big, selecting it into a Memory DC for drawing, calling `DrawFrameControl(..., DFC_BUTTON, DFCS_BUTTONCHECK | DFCS_FLAT | ..., ...)` twice as appropriate, then using that bitmap in the Image List (and saving the previous IL to restore when the window is enabled again).

---

Regarding the scroll bar, you cannot get access to the implicit scrollbar as a separate window, so I don't think you can easily make it look more disabled without resorting to more custom drawing hacks for the non-client area of the List View.

Or creating an explicit scroll bar control yourself, but then you need to make sure it behaves the same as the original one, changes when the list view items change, respects right-to-left locale and so on.

It might be a bit of a challenge to get all the offsets and possibly transparency right even for the custom checkbox images described above. Even though this is how the List View control itself does it, it might not be worth the effort in the end.